# jQuery grow image in place on mouseover

Tags: jquery, image, resize

I've got a bunch of gallery images that I display as small thumbnails (about 50px big). When the user mouses over the small image a larger one 'grows' out of it (up to 100px) so they can see it a little better.

I've got this code, which works out where the image is on the page, applies another image (absolutely positioned) over the top, then grows it.

```
$(document).on("mouseover", "img.grow", function() {
    var iid = $(this).attr("id");
    var isr = $(this).attr("src");
    var loc = $(this).offset();
    $("body").append('<img class="grown" id="o' + iid + '" src="' + isr + '" style="position: fixed; z-index: 1505; top: ' + loc.top + 'px; left: ' + loc.left + 'px; width: 33px;" />');
    $(".grown").animate({
        width: '100px', 
        marginLeft: '-25',
        marginTop: '-15'
    }, 250);
}).on("mouseleave", "img.grow", function() {
    var iid = $(this).attr("id");
    $("img#o" + iid).fadeOut(100, function() {
        $(this).remove(); 
    });
});
```

I'm getting the dreaded 'bounce' though - as the new image is placed on top of the original, it causes 'mouseleave' to fire. Obviously I don't want this to happen, but I need to use an absolutely positioned image to stop the layout being jiggled around.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, yes I do. To the source!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the easiest answer by far was to apply the mouseleave to the image created, rather than the one underneath.
Final code:

```
$(document).on("mouseover", "img.grow", function() {
    var iid = $(this).attr("id");
    var isr = $(this).attr("src");
    var loc = $(this).offset();
    $("body").append('<img class="grown" id="o' + iid + '" src="' + isr + '" style="position: fixed; z-index: 1505; top: ' + loc.top + 'px; left: ' + loc.left + 'px; width: 33px;" />');
    $(".grown").animate({
        width: '100px', 
        marginLeft: '-25',
        marginTop: '-15'
    }, 250);
}).on("mouseleave", "img.grow", function() {
    var iid = $(this).attr("id");
    $("img#o" + iid).fadeOut(100, function() {
        $(this).remove(); 
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Grimdotdotdot/FLB8E/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going about this the wrong way, its too messy. How about:

- Create a container at the full size you want to grow to
- Apply the image as a `BACKGROUND-IMAGE` with `x,y` position at `center,center`
- This image is the fullsize one but initially you set the `BACKGROUND-SIZE` to say 60%
- On hover animate this property

Or some similar process to this.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that each container took up the width of the full image with a little one sitting in the middle?

Comment: njeeeeeh `background-size` crossbrowser compatibility.